# Share option disappeared on windows 11

Tags: windows, sharing

No sharing option appears when I right-click on a file:
[image]

Here is the full context menu
[image]

Comment: Isn't it available in the ***Show more options*** menu?

Comment: No, It's not available anywhere.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the full context menu (Show more options)?

Comment: It appears to be a work in progress. Not in 22H2 but a share replacement in Insider

Comment: I added the full context menu picture. Please, check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Using Ultimate Windows Tweaker I was able to revert back  the "share" option on the windows 11 context menu.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLofu.png)

Here is the new context menu with the share option:
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMELz.png)

I don't have enough reputation, so I couldn't embed the photos. Please check the links.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Add or Remove Share Context Menu in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-share-context-menu-in-windows-11.1690/)
advises to create a `.reg` file containing the following text:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ModernSharing]
@="{e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7}"
```

Double-click the file, allow this registry modification,
then reboot.